# Using libmysql.dll on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, c, windows, pidgin

I have been working on a program which connects to libmysql.dll. In the part of the code that uses it, I have included both winsock2.h and mysql.h. I have written the program already and it works really well on both Linux and Windows XP.

For Windows XP, I have found that libmysql.dll must be in the system32 directory in order for the code to work. However, in Windows 7, even having the libmysql.dll file in system32 does not allow it to work. Apparently it could not find libmysql.dll. Given that this is a pidgin plugin, that is the only library that is not required by Pidgin, and therefore I had to place it somewhere. The problem is, I don't know where.

Where must it be placed on newer systems, like Windows 7?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The libmysql.dll file is a part of the MySQL Connector/C lib-

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Have you tried placing the file in the directory your application is being launched?

Unless the program that makes use of this dll was written in a way that it's searching for the dll in specific places (unlikely), it should work both ways - system32 or the program's running directory.

**Edit:**

Also make sure that the system32 dir exists in your %PATH% environment variable.

Comment: Thank you ! this actually helped me find another case that I have not yet tried, and it worked! :)

Comment: In my case, I had to put it on my running directory.

Comment: Note that it's not in the zip archives, but presumably it's in the msi versions. I got a copy from MySQL Workbench and that worked.